# Loading usercontrol dynamically not worked in ie11 and Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, user-controls

I have facing the problem when loading the user control content from main page.

Code below works fine up to Ie10, but worked in chrome.

**AsPX Code:**

```
<a href="javascript:activateTab('Section1')" style="text-decoration:none">Section 1 </a> 
<a href="javascript:activateTab('Section2')" style="text-decoration:none">Section 2 </a> 
<a href="javascript:activateTab('Section3')" style="text-decoration:none">Section 3 </a> 
<a href="javascript:activateTab('Section4')" style="text-decoration:none">Section 4 </a> 

<div id="page1" style="display: block;">    
     <ucl:Section1 ID="Section1" Visible="true" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" /> 
</div>
<div id="page2" style="display: none;">    
     <ucl:Section2 ID="Section2" Visible="true" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" /> 
</div>
<div id="page3" style="display: none;">    
     <ucl:Section3 ID="Section3" Visible="true" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" /> 
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
function activateTab(DivID)
{

 // Code here to enable the div based on click

}
```

After clicking the second link  browser hanked.

Anyone can suggest..?

Comment: can I see how you do get the element inside activateTab function?

Comment: I should have a possible solution but I need to see how `DivID` parameter is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue in coding..

I have using some `telerik` controls in same page, when removing the `telerik` controls working fine.